# Zend Layout - Header and Footers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I feel my problem is relatively simple.  I'm new to the Zend framework and I'd like to be able to call a controller to do some work for a header or a footer.  I've already created a HeaderController and a applications/views/scripts/headers/index.phtml - all I'm trying to do is get that data, and put it in my layout by default.

Everything works if I navigate to /header, by the by.

Edit:

Made some progress - if I add:

```
$this->render("header/index.phtml");
```

it renders all the static data, but doesn't seem to be running the HeaderController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bit of code out, be sure to disable the layout in your header controller, as the purpose is only to render a limited amount of content.

```
<?= $this->action('index', 'header', null, array('possible_args'=>'here')); ?>
```

The documentation can be seen here.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action

Comment: Thanks a million!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: Youre going about it the wrong way. You should be using ViewHelpers and/or ActionHelpers. Generally speaking a combination of a custom ViewHelper to assemble complex snippets of html given a set of parameters and then the `Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder` to place things from your view into your layout. As rule of thumb, pretty much any logic you might reserve for a controller that doesnt interact directly with the request or control the flow of the request lifecycle is ok to put in a view helper.

Comment: @prodigitalson Is that so?  I'm trying to create a Data Driven Header for the page.  I've seen it done else where with a controller, so that was my first thought.  I can look into your way as well...

Comment: I mean the `action` view helper will work dont get me wrong but its often criticized as potential performance hitter because it goes through the entire dispatch cycle to do its work - usually for something trivial by comparison. There are use cases for it but youre better off avoiding it.

Comment: @prodigitalson I mean it did work, however, I'd like it if noone could navigate to my header alone and get a really screwy page.  If ViewHelpers are the way to ensure that, I'd like to learn how.  As I said, I'm quite new to Zend

Comment: Well [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/1235/view-helpers-in-zend-framework/) by [Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://mwop.net/) pretty much lays it all out. That article is form 2008 so the examples are an older version of 1.x so you may need to make some API adjustments (ie. reference the current View and Layout docs), but the principles still stand.

Comment: Listen to prodigitalson, the entire approach is wrong. It is the equivalent to saying that you could fix your cars broken engine by pulling it with a tractor. Sure the car will move, but the engine will still be busted. Read up on ViewHelpers and ActionHelpers and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I agree. ViewHelper is the way to go for such things.